# Wildcard for sequential images

Tags: ffmpeg, jpeg, avconv

I'm trying to animate a series of jpg files using avconv.  Based on numerous examples, I'm trying using %d.jpg to specify the files.  Or %05d.jpg.  However, I'm getting:

```
avconv -i %d.jpg a.avi
avconv version 0.8.3-4:0.8.3-0ubuntu0.12.04.1, Copyright (c) 2000-2012 the Libav developers built on Jun 12 2012 16:37:58 with gcc 4.6.3
%d.jpg: No such file or directory
```

Here is a snip of my directory listing:

```
10380.jpg
10390.jpg
10400.jpg
1040.jpg
10410.jpg
10420.jpg
10430.jpg
10440.jpg
```

There are jpegs from 00000.jpg to 14400.jpg

I don't really understand that wildcard system, but that is what is in examples.

(note:  I tagged it ffmpeg because a tag for avconv does not exist, and avconv supersedes ffmpeg)

**Update**
I'm updating the question based on the answer below by @av501.

To begin with, I have a list of png files with sequential ordering by 10.  They have text preceding a 5 digit integer.  For example:

```
SkinMattekNutrient_py_00000.png
SkinMattekNutrient_py_00010.png
SkinMattekNutrient_py_00020.png
...
SkinMattekNutrient_py_10440.png
```

What would be the way to batch convert these to jpg?  I tried

```
convert ...
SkinMattekNutrient_py_%05d.png %05d.jpg
```

and

```
convert ...
SkinMattekNutrient_py_%5d.png %5d.jpg
```

But I get:

```
convert SkinMattekNutrient_py_%05d.png %05d.jpg
convert: missing an image filename `%05d.jpg' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3011.
```

Answer (score 7):

You need to use %5d for your files. But you seem to have two problems

For %5d to work you must have 5 digit numbering. [You have a 1040.jpg] and also consecutive. 00000.jpg then 00001.jpg. Your file names seem to be jumping by 10.

If all of them are multiple of 10, then you can use %d50.jpg  [But you still need to fix your 1040.jpg]

Otherwise the command line works here [I am using ffmpeg -i %5d.jpg out.avi and ffmpeg -i %5d0.jpg out.avi]

Comment: I updated my question to make it simpler -- simply about converting the png files to jpg.  I still can't figure out how to properly use the wildcard system.  I've tried searching, but can't find any explanations.  What would be the correct syntax?  Thanks.

Comment: convert is a different utility, right? ffmpeg is a different one. I am doing it using ffmpeg and it works fine here.

Comment: Regardless of which program I'm using, I'm getting the can't find file error.  I wonder what is wrong with my system?  All examples I've found show the same thing.

Answer (score 5):

Here's one way to batch-convert image files in a Bash shell:

```
for f in *.png; do ffmpeg -i "$f" "${f%.png}.jpg"; done
```

I believe this technique will work for any command which requires input and output files to be listed separately. In your case this would be:

```
for f in *.png; do convert "$f" "${f%.png}.jpg"; done
```